# PHP Swift login page error

Tags: php, swift, mcrypt

I am following the following course on how to create a login page with Swift and PHP for an iPhone app: https://www.udemy.com/swift-php-mysql-user-sign-up-sign-in-sign-out-and-more/learn/v4/content

I am stuck on the registration page PHP code, and it just says that the page isn't working. I have the following code:

```
require("../db/MySQLDAO.php");

$config = parse_ini_file('../../inc/SwiftCourse2.ini');

$returnValue = array();

if(empty($_REQUEST["userEmail"]) || empty($_REQUEST["userPass"]) 
        || empty($_REQUEST["firstName"])
        || empty($_REQUEST["lastName"]))
{
    $returnValue["status"]="400";
    $returnValue["message"]="Missing required information";
    echo json_encode($returnValue);
    return;
}

$userEmail = htmlentities($_REQUEST["userEmail"]);
$userPass = htmlentities($_REQUEST["userPass"]);
$firstName = htmlentities($_REQUEST["firstName"]);
$lastName = htmlentities($_REQUEST["lastName"]);

// Generate secure password       
$salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
echo $salt;
$secured_password = sha1($userPass . $salt);

$dbhost = trim($config["dbhost"]);
$dbuser = trim($config["dbuser"]);
$dbpassword = trim($config["dbpassword"]);
$dbname = trim($config["dbname"]);


$dao = new MySQLDAO($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname);
$dao->openConnection();

// Check if user with provided username is available
$userDetails = $dao->getUserDetails($userEmail);
if(!empty($userDetails))
{
    $returnValue["status"]="400";
    $returnValue["message"]="Please choose a different email address"; 
    echo json_encode($returnValue);
    return;
}



// Register new user
$result =$dao->registerUser($userEmail, $firstName, $lastName, $secured_password, $salt);
```

If I go to the page in a web browser, it shows "error 400: missing required information" which is what it's supposed to do, which leads me to believe my error is shortly after that code block. I give it the following postString `userEmail=alan@test.com&userPass=dynasty123&firstName=alan&lastName=raff` and the error occurs.

I started going line by line, and I found that when I echo'd out the variable $salt, it produced a lot of unknown characters that were represented with question marks. I'm not exactly sure what this line exactly does: `$salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);` so if someone could explain why that produces a lot of characters, I would appreciate it because my database is set up to only allow 16 characters on that field. When I enable verbose logging on my apache instance, I can see the salt being set to this: `'t\\x1E\\xFCC*\\xB3X\\xCB1'\\x05\\xA92\\xA1\\x90...'` which is more than 16 characters and could be causing my errors. Am I starting to get somewhere or am I way off? If anyone could help I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

`openssl_random_psuedo_bytes` generates a string of random bytes (characters) of the length you specified as the first parameter (12 in your case). It is part of the `openssl` extension for php which is not usually enabled in a standard installation of PHP.

**I would check that you have the `openssl` extension installed**.

Additionally, the tutorial you are following is either out of date or not very good. There is an inbuilt PHP password handling function that you should be using rather than `sha1` which is certainly not suited for password hashing. Please refer to the documentation on the [`password_hash` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the sha1. I'll modify my templates to use the password_hash function, because I did a little more research and that looks to be a more popular way of doing it. Also, my openssl extension is already installed. I used a PHPinfo page to see if it's installed, and my version is:  OpenSSL 1.0.2g 1 Mar 2016 

I'm confused as to what else I can try, so if you have any ideas that could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: Can you share any more details on the error you are getting? If the browser just shows "The page is not working" then you should check your webserver logs.

Comment: So I think I figured it out. I wasnt getting any specific error message, only an error 500. I enabled verbose logging on my PHP script and found out that it was a chain of a few issues, all stemming from a typo in a table in the database. I had "passsword" instead of "password." This led to a few other errors that after fixing those led me back to the typo. Thank you!